# Did Microsoft change query optimizer regarding number of files and parallelism

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, parallelism

Did Microsoft change query optimizer regarding number of files and parallelism? Does the optimizer no longer factor in the number of files to determine the degree of parallelism for a query? If so, does anyone know when the change was made? If not, can anyone provide a link to Microsoft documentation that discusses the topic (current documentation for either SQL Server 2014 or 2016)?

Answer (score 14):

That was an urban legend that [Microsoft's Bob Dorr debunked back in 2007](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2007/02/21/sql-server-urban-legends-discussed/):

> This information has been taken out of context and propagated
>   incorrectly as SQL Server has a thread per database file so adding
>   more files to a database can increase I/O performance.   Adding more
>   files and properly aligning them with storage can increase the I/O
>   performance for a variety of reasons but achieving new I/O threads per
>   file is NOT one of them.

Read the post for much more detail.